# Java Simple Factory with constructors using different parameters

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, factory, solid-principles

I have two ways of saving data in my application: save to database and save to file. Since I don't want client code dealing with construction of objects I created a class that (to my understanding) is simple factory with a factory method. Code below:

```
public static DataPersister createDataPersister(Boolean saveToDb, Session session, String filename) {
    if (saveToDb) {
        return new DatabaseDataPersister(session);
    } else {
        return new FileDataPersister(filename);
    }
}
```

With this setup client code doesn't have to deal with constructing anything or deciding whether to save to DB or file - it can just call a `save()` method on an object returned by the factory like so:

```
DataPersister dataPersister = DataPersisterSimpleFactory.createDataPersister(this.savetoDb, this.session, this.filename);
dataPersister.save(this.data);
```

My question is - is this solution breaking SOLID principles? In order to create e.g. a `DatabaseDataPersister` client code needs to pass on a `filename` parameter, and this implementation of `DataPersister` won't have any use of it. I feel like it doesn't sit right with something similar to Interface-segregation principle but not quite that.

And if the solution is indeed a code smell - how do I go about cleaning it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SOLID principle I think is in violation is DIP.

Your client classes, by having to depend on the static factory directly, have a compile-time dependency on actual implementations, `DatabaseDataPersister` and `FileDataPersister`, rather than just the abstraction `DataPersister`.

To solve, supply to the client the `DataPersister` you want them to use. The constructor is usually a good place for this:

```
public class ExampleClient {

    private final DataPersister dataPersister;

    public ExampleClient(DataPersister dataPersister) {
        this.dataPersister = dataPersister;
    }

    public void methodThatUsesSave(){
        dataPersister.save(data);
    }
}
```

This code compiles without the concrete implementations, i.e. it has no dependency on them. The client also doesn't need to know the `filename` or `session` so it solves that code smell too.

We can decide which concrete implementation to give it at construction time, here I use your existing method:

```
DataPersister dataPersister = DataPersisterSimpleFactory.createDataPersister(this.savetoDb, this.session, this.filename);
ExampleClient example = new ExampleClient(dataPersister);
```

Comment: I find your comment the most helpful. I can easily inject the correct `DataPresister` based on a command line argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect opportunity to use the factory pattern

```
interface DataPersister {
    void persist(String s);
}

private class DatabasePersister implements DataPersister {
    final Session session;

    public DatabasePersister(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(String s) {
        System.out.println("Persist to database: " + s);
    }
}

private class FilePersister implements DataPersister {
    final String filename;

    public FilePersister(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    @Override
    public void persist(String s) {
        System.out.println("Persist to file: " + s);
    }
}

class PersisterFactory {
    public DataPersister createDatabasePersister(Session session) {
        return new DatabasePersister(session);
    }

    public DataPersister createFilePersister(String filename) {
        return new FilePersister(filename);
    }
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    DataPersister databasePersister = new PersisterFactory().createDatabasePersister(new Session());
    databasePersister.persist("Hello");
    DataPersister filePersister = new PersisterFactory().createFilePersister("Hello");
    filePersister.persist("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Your code basically looks like mine except you handle the decision which concrete implementation of DataPersister to create in the client code (in your example, the `test()` method) and I wish to push the decision making somewhere else (in my example the factory decides what to create based on `saveToDb` boolean - which is by the way set based on a command line argument so the client doesn't decide on that either). Can you think of a solution where client code doesn't have to devcide? Is it possible, or even justifiable?

Answer (score 1):

You *already* pass a bunch of stuff irrelevant to various persisters.

As it stands you need a method that takes a `Session` and one that takes a `String` and you're done. No need for a boolean, no need for useless params. That handles your decision making with no cruft.

Whether or not that's a good idea... I'm ambivalent. You're not saving much; might as well just have a static factory in each type so it's explicit in the code what type you're creating.

Consider what happens when you add a new persister, like a REST endpoint, that would take a URL (could be a string, could be an actual URL). You now need even *more* useless parameters etc. Or you could pass in a URI from the beginning, e.g., `file://` or `http://` and get around that problem.

There are any number of ways this could be done–I'm not convinced there's a "clearly correct" answer, and it may boil down to opinion.

Comment: The boolean variable `saveToDb` is used by the factory to decide on which concrete implementation to create. Writing two separate methods for creation of two seperate implementations, like in @OldCurmudgeon answer, while helpful with getting rid of one variable, forfeits my goal of the client code not needing to decide which `DataPersister` implementation to instantiate.

Comment: @naru You're trading methods for variables-there's no logical difference; the client still decides. Possible? Sure-always pass all the variables: the DB doesn't need the filename, the file doesn't need the session. The other answer just needs a function that decides based on the parameter type, which is what I said as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well the right solution here is combining the dependency injection from weston and the factory pattern from OldCurmudgeon.

```
public class ExampleClient {

    private final DataPersister dataPersister;

    public ExampleClient(DataPersister dataPersister) {
        this.dataPersister = dataPersister;
    }

    public void methodThatUsesSave(){
        dataPersister.save(data);
    }
}

class PersisterFactory {
    public DataPersister createDatabasePersister(Session session) {
        return new DatabasePersister(session);
    }

    public DataPersister createFilePersister(String filename) {
        return new FilePersister(filename);
    }
}
```

The upper level code:

```
PersisterFactory = new PersisterFactory();
DataPersister dataPersister;
if (saveToDb)
    dataPersister = PersisterFactory.createDatabasePersister(new Session());
else
    dataPersister = PersisterFactory.createFilePersister("Hello");
ExampleClient example = new ExampleClient(dataPersister);
```

Usually the `dataPersister` comes from the DI container and the `saveToDb` comes from the config, but of course testing can be an exception.